# Не работает Скрипт в WebBrower (Delphi)

Tags: delphi

Пытаюсь написать бота, ну вот возникла ошибка, WebBrowser не хочет переходить на главную страницу сайта smmka.ru.. Получается при нажатии войти через вк, нечего не происходит, только обновление страницы, не подскажете в чем проблема?

Comment: покажи код, который за это отвечает...

Comment: Та смысл прост, я кидаю на форму webbrowser через навигатор перехожу, и в этом браузере пытаю войти через вк на страницу и нечего не происходит, может какие-то параметры в ie нужно сделать..хотя через ie заходит спокойно